# How to Detect css style by iPhone/iPad

Tags: c#, css

I want to change the css style according to the devices.

This is my .css file.

// Desktop

```
@media only screen and (min-width : 1224px)
{
    .page
    {
        width: 990px;
        margin-left: auto;
        margin-right: auto;
    }
    label
    {
        font-family: Verdana,Arial,sans-serif;
        font-size: 0.8em;
    }
}
```

// Ipad

```
@media only screen and (min-device-width : 768px) and (max-device-width : 1024px)
{    
    .page
    {
        width: 100%;
        margin-left: auto;
        margin-right: auto;
    }
    .Details
    {
        min-height: 125px;
        min-width: 500px;
    }

    label
    {
        font-family: Verdana,Arial,sans-serif;
        font-size: 0.8em !important;
    }
}
```

//Iphone

```
@media only screen and (min-device-width : 320px) and (max-device-width : 568px)
{    
  input[type="text"], input[type="password"]
    {
        width: 50px;
    }

}
```

But it didn't change. 
it changed only desktop. I pad and Iphone it was not working.
please tell me what is the wrong with my code.

Comment: A media query cannot detect a specific device type, like iPad or iPhone, just specific media properties.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
@media only screen and (min-width : 768px) and (max-width : 1024px)
```

and not

```
@media only screen and (min-device-width : 768px) and (max-device-width : 1024px)
```

You should also think about filling in the sizes you've not covered just in case users have an unusal screen size, beween 1024px and 1224 etc.